# Dudas sobre los estandares de C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un par de dudas

- ¿Cual es el estandar mas utilizado actualmente?
- Si hago un programa por ejemplo en el estandar C++14 ¿Afectara la portabilidad y ejecución del codigo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Cual es el estandar mas utilizado actualmente?

Es una respuesta complicada de responder. En mi caso el estándar actual es c++11 pero en unos meses cambiaremos de compilador y pasaremos a utilizar c++14.

En líneas generales presupongo que al resto le pasara algo similar. Hay varias razones para quedarse estancado en un estándar antiguo:

- dependencia de librerías de terceros sin mantenimiento. Al no compilarse para nuevos compiladores te obliga a estancarte hasta que le encuentres un reemplazo.
- sistemas embebidos. Algunos sistemas embebidos tienen compiladores con un mantenimiento marginal y esto hace que evolucionen más lentamente
- sistemas antiguos. Los nuevos compiladores pueden no estar disponibles para SO antiguos tipo MSDOS o Windows 95.

> Si hago un programa por ejemplo en el estandar C++14 ¿Afectara la portabilidad y ejecución del codigo?

El estándar C++14 introduce algunas novedades respecto a c++11 muchas respecto a c++03. Usar una de estas características impedirá que puedas compilar el código bajo un estándar más antiguo.

Answer (score 3):

#### ¿Cual es el estandar mas utilizado actualmente?

Pregunta trampa. Sin ser, ni mucho menos, un experto en C++, ni profesional del gremio, actualmente utilizo C++11, principalmente por las grandes mejoras en velocidad que proporciona, eliminando muchas operaciones de copia de instancias, que con estándares previos eran ineludibles.

C++11 proporciona una excelente compatibilidad *hacia atrás*, de forma que, con tan solo recompilar, obtenemos una mejora de eficiencia *gratis*.

Podemos considerarlo el *mínimo imprescindible* en proyectos actuales, y mas teniendo en cuenta que estamos en el 2017. Ese estándar tiene ya unos añitos.

#### Si hago un programa por ejemplo en el estandar C++14 ¿Afectara la portabilidad y ejecución del codigo?

Otra pregunta trampa. El código compilará en cualquier compilador que soporte C++14.

Si te refieres a la *facilidad* de encontrar un compilador con soporte para dicho estándar, `g++` es software libre, portado a mas plataformas de las que he visto en mi vida. No debería de ser un problema, salvo para entornos **muy concretos**.

Si te refieres a elementos *auxiliares*, tales como librerías, eso ya es otro tema. Por norma general, si están mantenidas, soportarán los nuevos estándares.

Como ya comenté, la compatibilidad *hacia atrás* es muy buena, por lo que la mayoría del software antiguo no tendrá problemas.